# HTTPS HTTP PROBLEM Authorisation Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: node.js, http, https, google-oauth

I am Using Oath20 for login and in google API when I was working locally using localhost it was working fine but when I deployed my Api ON
HEROKU it get successfully deployed but when tried to login with google it gives m error
[error what I am getting][1]

My herroku redirects http://help-blog.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback which is HTTPrequest
but google requires https
[Here google asking for HTTPS but my heroku redirecting to HTTP how to solve this?][2]

I am using my session in this way
[Session code ][3]

please tell how to solve this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCTqW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOyaC.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CktQg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configured your google login key you also specified a callback url. (screen 2)
This url should be https. i see http in the screen.
Enable https on heroku if its not enabled.

Comment: Thanks Rapheal for reply but heroku https already enabled by web app link https://help-blog.herokuapp.com/ but when I redirect it it than use HTTP i think it may be due to cookie? but I have not much understanding about express session and cookie i know basic info can you  see that portion please

Comment: did you add a "s" for https, in the second field of screen 2 ?